# SQL SERVER: I want Every id from the left table and if that Id is not available in right table than previous row data should get copied

Tags: sql-server

For Example :

Table 1:

```
ID
1 
2 
3 
4
```

Table 2:

```
ID  accNo Name Amount
1   111   aaa   400
3   111   aaa   450
1   222   ddd   500
```

Resulatnt table after join:

```
ID accNo Name Amount
1  111    aaa   400
2  111    aaa   400
3  111    aaa   450
4  111    aaa   450
1  222    ddd   500
2  222    ddd   500
3  222    ddd   500
4  222    ddd   500
```

I want Every id from the left table and if that Id is not available in right table than previous row data should get copied for that ID.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an outer [apply](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) you can lookup the values for each row. Just match by ID equal or less than the current row and get the first match in an Descending order so you get the highest ID with value.

```
select
    t1.ID,
    t2.Name,
    T2.Amount
from table1 t1
outer apply (
    select top 1
        *
    from table2 t2
    where
        t1.ID <= t2.ID
    order by
        ID DESC
) t2
```

EDIT:

```
select
    t1.ID,
    t2.Name,
    T2.Amount
from (
    select distinct
        t1.ID,
        t2.accNo
    table1 t1
    inner join table2 accNoTable on
        1=1
) t1
outer apply (
    select top 1
        *
    from table2 t2
    where
        t1.accNo = t2.accNo and
        t1.ID <= t2.ID
    order by
        ID DESC
) t2
```

Comment: Sorry @mxix for the Inconvenience that I caused. Can we solve the updated question also with the same approach?

Comment: No problem. You can, but first you need every combination for each ID and each accNo. Check the edit.

Comment: just changes the <= sign to >= and now It is working perfectly. Thanks @mxix for all the quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (Id int)
insert into @t values (1),(2),(3),(4)

declare @tt table (ID int,name varchar(10),amount int)
insert into @tt(ID,name,amount)values (1,'aaa',400), (4,'ddd',500)

;with cte as 
(

select top 6 t.id,name,amount,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY name )RN from @t t,@tt tt

),Cte2 As (

select ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY name )R,* from cte where cte.Id > 1
)
select R as Id,Name,amount from Cte2
```